# Define a quotient structure for $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ iff $a+d=b+c$ in terms of $+$ and $\times$ operators

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

This is a past paper exam question, I don't really understand how to define this quotient structure.

The relation is on $\Bbb{N}$

In the preceding question I proved that this relation is an equivalence.

The equivalence class of some (a,b), which I will denote $[(a,b)]_\sim$ = {(c,d) | a+d=b+c}

I then worked through a few example classes to determine the pattern and see if I could describe the quotient set:

$[(a,a)]_\sim = \{(c,c) | c \in \Bbb{N}\}  $

$[(1,2)]_\sim = \{(c,d) | c \in \Bbb{N} ,  1+d = 2+c\} = \{(c,c+1) | c \in \Bbb{N}\}$

$[(1,3)]_\sim = \{(c,d) | c \in \Bbb{N} ,  1+d = 3+c\} = \{(c,c+2) | c \in \Bbb{N}\}$

$[(2,1)]_\sim = \{(c,d) | c \in \Bbb{N} ,  2+d = 1+c\} = \{(c,c-1) | c \in \Bbb{N}\}$

Clearly, $\forall (a,b) \in \Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N}, [(a,b)]_\sim = \{(c,c+b-a) | c \in \Bbb{N}\}$

-

I feel like I've understood the relation, but the question asks me "By considering representative members of these classes, or otherwise, describe how operations of $+$ and $\times$ may be defined to form a quotient structure.", and I don't really understand that. Clearly, the quotient set is the set of all possible values of b-a, which is countably infinite. I don't understand how to define that using operations of + and X though.

Comment: What does $b-a$ mean in $\mathbb N$? Can you define that in general?

Comment: $(b-a) \in \Bbb(N) \Rightarrow \exists c \in \Bbb{N} s.t. a+c=b$? Then my quotient set is all c, which is surely \Bbb{N}?

Comment: But then what if $a>b$? What does $c+(b-a)$ mean? Is $[(a,b)]_{\sim}$ really empty if $a>b$, since $b-a$ is undefined?

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, when a>b, $[(a,b)]_\sim$ isn't empty, but the cardinality of the quotient set would be smaller than (a-b) elements. So am I looking to define (b-a)u(a-b) in this case?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by $(b-a)u(a-b)$.

Comment: Sorry, that's stupid notation. |(b-a)|, the absolute value of (b-a), so for $b,a \in \Bbb{N}, x=|(b-a)| \in \Bbb{N}$

Comment: Although from these other answers, I can see that I'm actually defining integers, so I was wrong to try to restrict it to naturals.

Comment: No, you aren't "wrong" to restrict to naturals. This is defining the integers in terms of the naturals. In the pair $(a,b)$, $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers, and you shouldn't try to do operations with them that do not make sense on the naturals.  That's the tricky part of this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem that there's really any motivation to define addition or multiplication in the quotient structure a certain way (at least, not from what you've posted), so here's a big motivation: $\Bbb N/\sim$ is quite often how the set of integers is *defined* using $\Bbb N$. The idea is that $(a,b)$ represents $a-b$ (which needn't make any sense if we're dealing only with natural numbers), and that $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ iff $a-b=c-d$. In the context of integers, this is of course equivalent to $a+d=b+c$, but since we're dealing with natural numbers only, we need to use the "$a+d=b+c$" version.

I will (temporarily) call the addition and multiplication operations on $\Bbb N/\sim$ by $\oplus$ and $\odot$, to distinguish from the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ on $\Bbb N$. The operation $-$ will represent subtraction on the integers as we're used to (that is, as a superset of $\Bbb N$, rather than being derived as a quotient of $\Bbb N$), just to give us an idea of what we need to happen with $\oplus$ and $\odot$.
Now, $$(a-b)+(c-d)=(a+c)-(b+d),$$ so we'll need $$[(a,b)]_\sim\oplus[(c,d)]_\sim:=[(a+c,b+d)]_\sim.$$ Also, $$(a-b)\cdot(c-d)=a\cdot c-a\cdot d-b\cdot c+b\cdot d=(a\cdot c+b\cdot d)-(a\cdot d+b\cdot c),$$ so we'll need $$[(a,b)]_\sim\odot[(c,d)]_\sim:=[(a\cdot c+b\cdot d,a\cdot d+b\cdot c)]_\sim.$$

You should be able to show that each $\sim$-equivalence class has a unique representative $(a,b)$ such that $a=1$ or $b=1$ (or $a=b=1$). This should help you to prove that $\oplus$ and $\odot$ are in fact well-defined.

Once we're done with that, we can call $\Bbb N/\sim$ by "$\Bbb Z$", noting that $[(1,1)]_\sim$ is the $\oplus$-identity element of $\Bbb Z$ and that $[(2,1)]_\sim$ is the $\odot$-identity element. Also, for any $[(a,b)]_\sim\in\Bbb Z$, the $\oplus$-inverse of $[(a,b)]_\sim$ is $[(b,a)]_\sim$. Now, we have a natural inclusion $\Bbb N\to\Bbb Z$ given by $n\mapsto[(n+1,1)]_\sim$, and you can see that this inclusion maps $n+m$ to $[(n+1,1)]_\sim\oplus[(m+1,1)]_\sim$ and maps $n\cdot m$ to $[(n+1,1)]_\sim\odot[(m+1,1)]_\sim.$

This inclusion's operational compatibility allows us to simply call $[(n+1,1)]_\sim$ by "$n$" and $[(1,n+1)]_\sim$ by "$-n$" for all (positive) $n\in\Bbb N$, and we call $[(1,1)]_\sim$ by "$0$"; likewise, call $\oplus$ by "$+$" and $\odot$ by "$\cdot$." In this way, we effectively treat $\Bbb N$ as a substructure of this new structure $\Bbb Z$ that we've constructed (and which has all the properties we're used to), while at the same time simplifying the notation we were using in $\Bbb Z$ before.

Comment: Thankyou! This seems to make sense, both in the motivation and the actual approach. Accepted this one, thanks!

Comment: No problem! Actually, your noting of the quotient set was **very** relevant, since if you'd further realized that the set of all possible values $b-a$ was in fact the set of all integers, then that would have given you another motivation to define addition and multiplication as described above on your quotient set.

Comment: Yep, that's definitely the point I missed here. I was thinking of b-a as |b-a|, which would make it naturals and left me confused what I was actually trying to define.

Answer (score 4):

You have for example 
$$\begin{align}[(1,2)]=[(42,43)]&=\{(a,a+1)\mid a\in\mathbb N\}\\
[(1,1)]=[(42,42)]&=\{(a,a)\mid a\in\mathbb N\}\\
[(7,3)]=[(42,38)]&=\{(a+4,a)\mid a\in\mathbb N\}
\end{align}$$
We'd like to define an addtion on $\mathbb N^2$ such that $(a,b)\sim(a',b')$ and $(c,d)\sim(c',d')$ implies $(a,b)+(c,d)\sim(a',b')+(c'd')$. If we can, this allows us to define an addition on $\mathbb N^2/\sim$ by letting $[(a,b)]+[(c,d)]=[(a,b)+(c,d)]$. Fortunately, the straightforward idea of componentwise additon works:
If $a+b'=a'+b$ and $c+d'=c'+d$ then $(a+c)+(b'+d')=(a+b')+(c+d')=(a'+b)+(c'+d)=(a'+c')+(b+d)$ i.e. $(a+c,b+d)\sim(a'+c',b'+d')$.
It turns out that this makes $\mathbb N^2/\sim$ an abelian group with neutral element $[(1,1)]$ and where the inverse of $[(a,b)]$ is $[(b,a)]$.
We have an embedding (an injective monoid homomorphism) $\iota\colon \mathbb N\to\mathbb N^2/\sim$ given by $\iota(n)=[(n+1,1)]$.

With this in mind we note that $[(a,b)]=\iota(a)-\iota(b)$ (where the subtraction is taken in $\mathbb N^2/\!\sim\,$!).

This suggests that we *want* our multiplication to satisfy
$$[(a,b)]\cdot [(c,d)] = (\iota(a)-\iota(b))\cdot(\iota(c)-\iota(d))=\iota(a)\iota(c)+\iota(b)\iota(d)-\iota(a)\iota(d)-\iota(b)\iota(c).$$
This motivates us to try to define $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac+bd,ad+bc)$. It turns out, this works and ultimately makes $\mathbb N^2/\sim$ a commutative ring with unit, henceforth denoted by $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thankyou very much, I can see where you're coming from for the first half of this, but some of these concepts are new to me, and certainly wouldn't be in my exam. We've never mentioned an abelian group, nor an embedding as you mention. Sorry, and thankyou for your answer.

Comment: @CallumM Those terms are more technical, so you needn't worry about them much now. However, a group in general is a set $G$ together with an *associative* operation $+$ in $G$ that takes two elements in $a,b\in G$ and gives another *unique* $a+b\in G$, and such that: there exists an *identity element* for which $a+e=e+a=a\;\;\forall a\in G$ and each element has an inverse in $G$, that is, an element for which $a+a'=a'+a=e$. If the operation is in addition *commutative*, (...)

Comment: (...) we call the group *abelian*, and usually use $+$ to denote the operation. $\Bbb N$ is the "most famous" monoid (scratch out "inverses" from the axioms that define a group), while $\Bbb Z$ is the "most famous" abelian group.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Thanks for the explanation, it makes more sense now - the end is still very odd, but I wouldn't expect it to make perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that the quotient is just the set of integers. Indeed any class in $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N/_\sim$ will be either equivalent to $(a,0)$ or $(0,a)$ for some non-negative integer $a$ (I am assuming that $0\in\mathbb N$). Then you think of $(a,0)$ as $+a$ and of $(0,a)$ as $-a$. Then you can define addition and multiplication accordingly:

$$(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$$

$$(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac+bd,bc+ad)$$

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to figure out a big "hint" here that doesn't spell out what this problem is doing, so I'm just going to spell it out:

> This problem is defining the integers based on the natural numbers.

Basically, $(a,0)$ means $+a$, a positive integer, and $(0,a)$ means $-a$.

In general if $a<b$ then $(a,b)\sim (0,c)$ for some $c$. If $a=b$ then $(a,b)\sim(0,0)$. If $a>b$ then $(a,b)\sim (c,0)$ for some $c$.

Then, intuitively, $(a,b)$ is "representing" the integer $a-_zb$, where $-_z$ is some unknown binary operation we'd want to have but don't have yet. Then how would you add $(a-_zb)+(c-_zd)$ if you wanted it to be of the form $x-_zy$ with $x,y\in \mathbb N$?  How would you multipliy $(a-_zb)\times (c-_zd)$ to get $u-_z v$ with $u,v\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I think the blanks here are explained in the accepted answer, but this is very useful too.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, $(a,b)_\sim$ represents the integer $a-b$.

Now, we the relation is $(a,b)\sim (c,d)\iff a+c=b+d$

Note that we might "identify" an integer as the unique solution to $a+x=b$, which we might then start to call $a-b$. Note that if $a+d=b+c$ then $$b+x=a$$

$$b+d+x=a+d$$

$$b+d+x=b+c$$

and since $c$ is a natural, the cancellation law means

$$d+x=c$$

It follows this relation partitions the natural numbers into classes that "preserve" the unique solution to an equation. So $b+x=a$ and $d+x=c$ are equivalent when $(a,b)\sim (c,d)$. Since if $b+x'=a$, $d+x=c$, then $$(b+d)+(x+x')=(c+a)$$ $$(a+c)+x''=(b+d)$$ where $x''$ is our "new" solution, it is but natural to sum these classes as $$(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$$

So, suppose that $(a,b)$ is "the solution" to $b+x=a$ and $(c,d)$ is "the solution" to $d+x'=c$. Then we'd like to know what $(a,b)\times (c,d)$ is the solution to. Multiplying gives $$(b+x)(d+x')=ac$$

$$ad+bx'+dx+xx'=ac$$

We need to get rid of $bx'$ and $dx'$. The trick is to note that $$db+dx=da$$ and $$bd+bx'=bc$$ so that after adding one more $db$,

$$(db+dx)+(bx'+bd)+xx'=bd+ac$$

$$da+bc+xx'=bd+ac$$

$$(bc+ad)+xx'=(bd+ac)$$

All in all this tells us that it is natural to define $$(a,b)\times (c,d)=(ac+bd,ad+bc)$$

**ADD** Check that this two newly defined operations are such that

$(0)$ The resulting class ${\bf a }+{\bf b }$ and ${\bf a }\times {\bf b }$ is *independent* of which element in $x\in {\bf a }$ and which element $y\in {\bf b }$ we pick to carry out the operation.

$(1)$ There exists a class, which we shall denote by $\bf 0$, for which ${\bf a }+{\bf 0 }={\bf 0}+{\bf a }={\bf a }$ for any class $a$.

$(2)$ For any two classes ${\bf a }+{\bf b }={\bf b }+{\bf a }$ and  $({\bf a }+{\bf b })+{\bf c}={\bf a }+({\bf b }+{\bf c})$

$(3)$ There exists a class which we shall denote ${\bf 1}$ for which ${\bf 1}\times {\bf b}={\bf b}\times {\bf 1}=  {\bf b}$

$(4)$ For each class ${\bf a}$ there exist a class ${\bf b}$ for which ${\bf a}+{\bf b}=\bf 0$. We shall denote this (unique) class by ${\bf -a }$.

**BONUS** Build $\Bbb Q$ from $\Bbb Z$ by considering the relation $\simeq$ in $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\smallsetminus \{0\}$ for which $(a,b)\simeq (c,d)\iff ad=bc$ and giving $(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\smallsetminus \{0\})/\simeq$ and appropriate structure. In this case, multiplication will be the easy one, and summation will be "strange".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The proof for (a,b).(c,d) is especially useful.

Comment: In the bonus, it should be $\mathbf Q=(\mathbf Z\times(\mathbf Z\setminus\{0\}))/\simeq$, right?

Comment: @MichaelCorleone Yes!

Comment: Ok +1(as soon as I can vote again in a few hours) good answer

Answer (score 2):

Below I explain (from *scratch*) the motivation, since many textbooks omit such. The goal is to construct the *ring* $\,\Bbb Z\,$ from the *semiring* $\Bbb N.\,$ (A [semiring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) is that structure obtained from a ring by dropping the hypothesis on existence of additive inverses ("negatives"). So, informally, a semiring is a "ring without negatives", sometimes (jokingly?) called a *rig*, i.e. "ri$\rm\color{#c00}n$g" without $\rm\color{#c00}n$ = $\rm\color{#c00}n$egatives).

We wish to construct, in the most general way, a ring $\,\Bbb Z\,$ containing the semiring $\,\Bbb N.\:$ Here, "most general" means two things. First, $\rm\,\Bbb Z\,$ should contain no elements other than what are needed for it to be a ring containing $\,\Bbb N.\,$ Note that $\,\Bbb Z\,$ must contain some elements not in $\rm\,\Bbb N,\:$ e.g. an additive inverse of $\,1,\,$ denoted $\,-1.\:$ But, as we shall see, it need not contain a multiplicative inverse of $\,2.\:$ Second, besides minimizing the underlying set, we also seek to minimize the assumptions, to keep the constructed object as general as possible. So we desire that no equalities are true in $\,\Bbb Z\,$ other than those equalities true in $\,\Bbb N,\,$ and those equalities implied by the ring axioms, e.g. $\rm\:-1 + 1 = 0.\:$

Let's consider the first constraint. We seek a set to represent $\,\Bbb Z.\: $ By hypothesis, $\,\Bbb Z\,$ contains $\,\Bbb N.\,$ Being a ring, it must contain an additive inverse $\rm\,-b\,$ for every $\rm\,b\in\Bbb N.\:$ Being closed under addition, $\,\Bbb Z\,$ must contain all elements of the form $\rm\,a + (-b) =: a-b \,$ for all $\rm\,a,b\in\Bbb N.\:$ No further elements are needed, since, using the ring axioms, and consequences (e.g. law of signs), one can easily check that set of element of this form are closed under all ring operations, e.g.

$\begin{eqnarray}\rm (1)\qquad\qquad &&\rm\qquad -(a\! -\! b)&=&\rm b\! -\! a\\
\rm(2)\qquad\qquad &&\rm a\!-\!b\, +\, \hat a\!-\!\hat b&=&\rm a\!+\!\hat a\, -\, (b\!+\!\hat b)\\
\rm(3)\qquad\qquad &&\rm (a\!-\!b)\,\ (\hat a\!-\!\hat b)&\,=\,&\rm a\hat a\!+\!b\hat b\,-\,(a\hat b\!+\!\hat a b)
\end{eqnarray}$

To construct $\,\Bbb Z\,$ set-theoretically, we can represent the element $\rm\:a\!-\!b\:$ by a pair $\rm\:(a,b)\in\Bbb N^2.\:$ However, it is not true that $\rm\:(a,b) = (\hat a,\hat b)\iff a=\hat a,\, b=\hat b\:$ since the ring axioms imply various equalities, e.g. $\rm\:a\!-\!a = b\!-\!b,\;$ so $\rm\:(a,a) = (b,b).\:$ Such equalities induce an equivalence relation $\sim$ on our pair representation $\rm\,\Bbb N^2.\ $ Comparing two general elements of this form we find

$\begin{eqnarray}\rm(4)\qquad\quad\ \  a\!-\!b &\,=\,&\rm \hat a\!-\!\hat b &\iff&\rm a+\hat b &=\,&\rm \hat a+b\\
\rm so\ \ \ \ (a,\,b) &\sim&\,\rm (\hat a,\,\hat b) &\iff&\rm a+\hat b &= &\rm \hat a+b\end{eqnarray}$

which is the equivalence relation specified in your exercise. Thus, recalling our second constraint of minimizing equalities, since these equalities are forced by the ring axioms, we must include them in our equivalence relation. It turns out that no other equalities are needed, since we can show that the resulting quotient structure forms a ring. Namely, let the underlying set of $\rm\,\Bbb Z\,$ be the quotient set $\,\Bbb N^2/\sim.\:$ Next, transport the ring structure from the elements $\rm\:a\!-\!b\:$ to the pairs $\rm\:(a,b)\:$ by translating the operations $\,(1),(2),(3)\,$ to pair operations, e.g.

$\qquad\qquad\ \ \begin{eqnarray}
\rm (a\!-\!b)\,\ (\hat a\!-\!\hat b)\!\! &\,=\,&\rm a\hat a\!+\!b\hat b-(a\hat b\!+\!\hat a b)\\
\to\quad\rm\ \ (a,\,b) \ (\hat a,\,\hat b)\ &=&\rm (a\hat a\!+\!b\hat b,\ a\hat b\!+\!\hat a b)\end{eqnarray}$

However, since the definitions of these operations employ particular representatives of the equivalence classes, we must check that the definitions are well-defined, i.e. independent of such choices. That is the task presented to you in the exercise. Then you will need to verify the ring axioms, and that $\,\Bbb N\,$ embeds in $\,\Bbb Z.$

**Remark** $\ $ This is a special case of a general construction: the *ring of differences* of an additively cancellative semiring. It is a sort of additive analog of the construction of fraction fields and localizations.

Comment: +1 This is very nice though probably over the OP's level, but it can help others to understand this stuff. One little thing, only: perhaps where it is written "most general" I'd write (added or instead) "as restrictive as possible", or something that'd convey the idea of minimality.

Comment: This is definitely above the level we're working at, but it is interesting to see the motivation behind defining that relation at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the essence of the relation. Take for example the equivalence class of $\,(1,2)\,$:

$$(a,b)\sim(1,2)\iff a+2=b+1\iff b-a=1$$

So you have a pretty well and nicely defined equiv. class:

$$[(1,2)]:=\{\;(a\,,\,a+1)\;;\;a\in\Bbb N\;\}$$

Also

$$(a,b)\sim (7,3)\iff a+3=7+b\iff b-a=-4\implies$$

$$[(a,b)]=\{\;(a\,,\,a-4)\;;\;a\in\Bbb N\;\}\ldots\text{etc.}$$

Then, assuming that for you $\,\Bbb N:=\{1,2,3,...\}\,$ ,you can take a representative for each equiv. class with say minimal first coordinate, say in the two examples above $\,(1,2)\;,\;(5,1)\,$ , and now you can define, say:

$$(1,2)+(5,1):=(6,3)\;,\;(1,2)\cdot(5,1):=(5,2)$$

or in any other way you want (I really don't understand what you mean by "quotient structure"...)

Comment: $b-a=-4$ and, more importantly $a-4$ makes no sense in the natural numbers. Just say $a-b=4$.

Comment: Isn't that what I had for [(1,2)]? I used c instead of a, but it looks the same to me. I'm not sure I see what I missed of the relation, my generalisation holds for both [(1,2)] and [(7,3)]. 

Quotient structure is just the structure of the quotient set, I believe. It wasn't defined in lectures, but quotient set was, so I believe the question is defining that quotient set (in terms of + and x).

I also don't understand how we can define that quotient set by minimal first co-ordinate - (1,2) is not related to (1,3). I think (b-a) is the only adequate quotient structure.

Comment: $(a,b)\times (c,d)=(ab,cd)$ is not going to be very effective - if $(a_1,b_1)\sim(a_2,b_2)$ is $(a_1,b_1)\times(c,d)\sim(a_2,b_2)\times(c,d)$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, of course they do sense: what is then $\,2-6\,$? That some operation between natural numbers isn't a natural number it doesn't matter at all *unless* one wants that operation to be *within* the natural numbers, and I don't want to: what I want is an easy way to define equiv. classes.  Besides this, it is trivially true that $\,b-a=-4\iff a-b=4\,$, so then it'd be "right"??

Comment: @Don The intended "quotient structure" is the *ring* $\,\Bbb Z.\:$ Thus one needs to show that the relation is not only an equivalence relation, but, further, a *congruence*, i.e. that it respects the operations, i.e $\rm\:a'\equiv a,\ b'\equiv b\:\Rightarrow\:a'+b'\equiv a+b,\:$ and similarly for other operations.

Comment: No, $2-6$ is not a natural number. You can't suddenly start working in the integers, when (hint) this problem is defining the integers from the natural numbers. So before you've defined the integers, what is $-4$? $a-b$ is not a fully defined binary function on that natural numbers because of this.

Comment: That's fine and I think it even reinforces my point, @Math: it doesn't matter whether some condition to *characterize* equiv. classes is some operation in the naturals, in the compelx or in the moon. It only matters it makes sense and helps. BTW, this is a not-so-pretty way to construct the integers' group by means of a nasty monoid...

Comment: That this problem is trying to build the integers from the naturals is a logical deduction that you and I can assume, yet the OP may have no the slightest idea what's going on and, unless specifically told otherwise, he can assume all the usual sets of numbers are as his command. The $\,b-a\,$ is *just* for characterization, nothing else. Now, **if** the specified target is the integers or if it is specifically determined that *only* naturals can be used I'd agree with you.

Comment: @Don This is a special case of a general construction: the *ring of differences* of an additively cancellative [semiring.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) It is an additive analog of the construction of fraction fields. My prior comment was intended in reply to your remark to the OP that  "I really don't understand what you mean by 'quotient structure'."

Comment: @MathGems, perhaps but I bet the OP has no idea about it (obviously, otherwise he wouldn't have asked this question). I'm trying to approach his question in the most naive, elementary way I can, without assuming and/or restricting myself unduly.

Comment: @Don Yes, I realize that. I was merely replying to your remark, and, further, adding some general context. (I did not downvote).

Comment: I'm the downvoter because your definition of multiplication did not meet the basics needed for a quotient - you need $u\sim v$ and $w\sim x$ to imply that $u\cdot w\sim v\cdot x$. Your definition (or at least your implied definition) for $\cdot$ doesn't give that.

Comment: But that was only *a suggestion*: do you really think I don't know that think *never* succeed to keep some signal of algebraic structure? That's the reason I wrote to the OP "...any other way you want..." , remarking the fact that I didn't know what he meant by "quotient structure"...which, BTW, seems to me *not* a standard term. Of course it really doesn't matter: I'm used to nonsensical/inconsiderate/patronizing downvotes .One more, one less...

Comment: The now accepted answer (pretty good, btw) begins in a very interesting way, which is precisely the info the OP seems to have ommited. Some guessed better, some guessed worse and some (like me) didn't guess at all, but gave some ideas to try to push the OP in the direction that he may choose.

Comment: Sure, I completely missed the motivation that the relation can define integers. Sorry about the term quotient structure too, it was in the paper and I don't have a solid definition - I imagine it's something the lecturer used last year before writing this paper. I took it to mean describing the quotient set, and the solutions here seem to indicate that as appropriate.

Comment: @Don I added an answer explaining the motivation of the construction (from scratch). I'd be grateful for any feedback, esp. comments that help to improve points which are not clear.