# The multiplication of differences has the cancellation property respect the equivalent relation $\underset{d}\sim$ between differences.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Definition**

A difference is a pair of natural numbers and if $x:=(m,n)$ and $y:=(p,q)$ are differences we define $x\underset{d}\sim y$ if and only if $m+q=p+n$.

**Theorem**

The relation $\underset{d}\sim$ between differences is a equivalence relation.

*Proof*. Omitted

**Definition**

The multiplication $\cdot$ is the operation in $N\times N$ defined through the condition
$$
(m,n)\cdot(p,q):=(mp+nq,mq+np)
$$
for any pair of differences.

**Lemma**

The multiplication has the cancellation proprerty respect the relation $\underset{d}\sim$ that is if $x,\,y$ and $z$ are differences then $x\underset{d}\sim y$ if and only if $x\cdot z\underset{d}\sim y\cdot z$ provided that $z\neq(m,m)$ for any $m\in\Bbb N$.

So unfortunately I don't be able to prove the last statement: so could someone help me, please?

Comment: Proving an if-and-only-if statement reduces to proving two implications. Can you prove that if $x\sim y$ then $x\cdot z\sim y\cdot z$? (In this direction, you shouldn't even need the assumption that $z$ is not of the form $(m,m)$.) Is it the converse implication that is giving you trouble at the moment?

Comment: @GregMartin Okay, you are right. However do you know the answer?

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/355336/242) for some motivation of this construction of $\Bbb Z$ from $\Bbb N.\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First suppose that $x\sim y$, where $x=\langle m,n\rangle$ and $y=\langle p,q\rangle$, and let $z=\langle a,b\rangle$. Then $$x\cdot z=\langle ma+nb,mb+na\rangle$$ and $$y\cdot z=\langle pa+qb,pb+qa\rangle\,,$$ so we want to show that

$$ma+nb+pb+qa=mb+na+pa+qb\,.\tag{1}$$

We know that $m+q=n+p$, so we have

$$\begin{align*}
ma+nb+pb+qa&=(m+q)a+(n+p)b\\
&=(n+p)a+(m+q)b\\
&=mb+na+pa+qb\,,
\end{align*}\tag{2}$$

as desired. Note that for this direction we don’t need to assume that $a\ne b$; we do need that for the other direction, so suppose that $a\ne b$, and $x\cdot z\sim y\cdot z$. Then $(1)$ holds, and we want to show that $m+q=n+p$. Exactly how this is to be done depends on what facts about $\Bbb N$ you’ve already proved.

If you know that since $a\ne b$ there is a $c\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that either $b=a+c$ or $a=b+c$, you can use some of the work from $(2)$ to conclude that without loss of generality you can assume that $a<b$ and conclude that $b=a+c$ for some $c\in\Bbb Z^+$, you can use the calculation in $(2)$ and cancellation for addition in $\Bbb N$ to conclude that $(n+p)c=(m+q)c$, and from here it should be clear what to do (and why you don’t want $c$ to be $0$).

In case it’s not been made clear, the intuition here is that $\langle m,n\rangle$ represents the difference $m-n$ in $\Bbb Z$, and the fact that $$(m-n)(p-q)=(mp+nq)-(mq+np)$$ explains the definition of multiplication.

Comment: Okay, all clear. Thanks too much for your assistance!!!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: You’re welcome!